# Can I use Delphi to write to BDE and PHP to read from it?

Tags: php, delphi, bde

I *strongly* prefer not to use additional 3rd party components, libraries or DLLs (at least in v1.0), unless there is absolutely no other solution.

Question: (how) can I use Delphi to progrtiamatically crate a BDE database and write to it, then use PHP to read from it?

Any URLs for examples of tutorial?

---

People are advising against it. Ok, the ultimate goal is some form of ODBC interface anyway. Someone mentioned ADO to me, but I don't see how to install it.

I need to crate the entire database and contents programatically in Delphi - **at run time** - I have no idea of it's contents or even name at compile time.

What's the simplest route for me?  Thanks

Comment: Once you have installed an ODBC driver for Firebird, (e.g. http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=odbc) or MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html), you can use the components on the ADOExpress/DBGo tab to connect to them.  You will have to check that your edition of Delphi includes the DBGo components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a bad idea to me, to be honest.  BDE is long-since deprecated and I seriously doubt if you could get PHP to jive with it.

I would recommend using a standard database such as Firebird or MySQL for which established Delphi and PHP libraries exist, or XML if the dataset is not too large.

Comment: I have real scenario need this. My client already has a desktop application (store management such as items, inventories, etc) uses BDE. i.e the application write to the database. He need to just view the information from this database remotely from anywhere. Indeed he has many store locations each one has its own copy of the application. The suggested solution that I could able to do, making PHP application could read this database from local server connected to the internet. Regardless BDE is depricated or not I need to know how to make it accessible from the ODBC?

Answer (score 2):

By BDE you mean Paradox or DBase? Wouldn't recomment using those anymore. I moved into Firebird and MySQL years ago just like Alan recommends.

Delphi supports Firebird/Interbase database out of the box AFAIK and PHP libraries exist for it. Other way around : MySQL support is in all PHP installations and there are some very good components for Delphi

Comment: "Delphi supports Firebird/Interbase database out of the box AFAIK" - I'm still stuck with Delphi 7 :-(

Comment: + 1 "there are some very good components for Delphi" - can you name some?

Comment: MyDac looks good, so +1, but unfortunately it isn't ODBC and I can't guarantee to always use MySql. Thanks for the comment, though